# How to put message into Sent?

Tags: java, email, imap, jakarta-mail, message

After sending the message with JavaMail by smtp, how to put it into the Sent folder(IMAP)?
What about the non-english mail(ex: in Russian sent=отправленные)? Is there a way to get the name of the "sent" folder programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folder.appendMessages()

There's no standard name for the "sent" folder.  Depending on the mail client being used, the folder might have a different name.  There's an IMAP extension that would tell you which folder is the "sent" folder, but I don't think most servers support the extension.

Comment: There is no solution for detect the name of "Sent" folder for any mail client? I think my mail client should create his folder, and put the messages in it.

Comment: No, there's no general solution.  You may need to implement a bunch of heuristics that try to guess what the user is using.

Comment: A solution is to create a database on a server with all translations of Sent folder, and get the name of it by API. But how to get the language? May be by other names, or to make a language-choose page. I think I'll create a page, where the user can select the "Sent" folder, "Spam" etc...

Answer (score 0):

In general, the Sent Folder doesn't have a fixed name.  Gmail, specifically supports 'special use extensions' for Folders.  When you do a LIST to get the list of email boxes, it will tag the sent folder with a \Sent tag.

See [Gmail's document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions) for their implemented extensions.