# Are folder name universals? [JavaMail]

Tags: java, android, email, client, jakarta-mail

Are JavaMail IMAP name universals?
Ex: are folder Sent for non English mail server universal?
For russian Sent = Отправленные.
If no, how to get the "Russian" name for the Sent folder?

Comment: I answered this in your other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619891/how-to-put-message-into-sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder names are based on the the mail service, not the language. For example, gmail might call it "Sent" but my school email might call it "outbox". This will obviously extend to services that are in different languages. So to answer your question, no folder names are not universal.